# Member Avatar doesn't appear in the welcome embed

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I am trying to make my bot send a welcome message when someone joins a specific server.

Code:

```
if member.guild.id == 928443083660607549:
        new = nextcord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="new")
        channel = bot.get_channel(996767690091925584)
        embed = nextcord.Embed(title="welcome to ikari!", description="・make sure to read the rules in <#928443083698360397> \n ・for more questions refer to <#928507764714651698>", color=0x303136)
        embed.set_author(name=f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}", icon_url=member.display_avatar_url)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.guild.icon.url)
        await channel.send(f"{member.mention}!", embed=embed)
        await member.add_roles(new)Error:
```

Error:

`AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'display_avatar_url'`

Comment: You need to use `member.avatar.url`

Answer (score 1):

Discord.py v2 changed the variables. Meaning that `.avatar_url` is now `.avatar.url`. `.icon_url` is now `.icon.url`. Hence meaning that `member.display_avatar.url` is what you're looking for.

This also means that stuff like `.avatar_with_size(...)` for example have now been changed to `.avatar.with_size(...)`. Just for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py now has different variables for display avatars etc.

Just edit this line:
`embed.set_author(name=f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}", icon_url=member.display_avatar_url)`
to
`embed.set_author(name=f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}", icon_url=member.display_avatar.url)`

If this answer has worked, please mark it as the correct answer! :)